# How to open windows desktop when using vagrant on mac os?

Tags: windows, macos, vagrant

I am running vagrant to boot up a windows environment on mac os x Yosemite. I found that 'vagrant rdp' is only supported in windows. Then how could I be able to open the desktop of a windows virtual machine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You also need to have a RDP client installed. Install the Microsoft Remote Desktop app from here: https://itunes.apple.com/en/app/microsoft-remote-desktop/id715768417?mt=12

Then in the terminal:

`vagrant rdp`

The Remote Desktop app will launch automatically.

Answer (score 4):

If you haven't already done so, you will need to set the communicator and network ports in your Vagrant file as follow:

```
  config.vm.communicator = "winrm"

  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", host:3389, guest: 3389
```

The Vagrant example for this has a video that shows it working a Mac, so it should all be possible: 
https://www.vagrantup.com/blog/feature-preview-vagrant-1-6-windows.html

Comment: I was going to use the desktop instead of headless vm. So I think @Brandon's solution is better.